# App crashes when i run with this error "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000001e1a40"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

[image]I'm using a segment controllers for show tableview , I want Underline for selected index, This is my function , I don't know what is wrong with this.`

```
func attributedText(){
    guard let font = UIFont(name: "DIN Condensed Bold", size: 20.0) else {
        return
    }
    let titleTextAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:  UIColor.white.cgColor,NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,NSAttributedString.Key.font : font]
    let withoutUnderLine: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:  UIColor.white.cgColor,NSAttributedString.Key.font : font ]
    if seasonsAndPointSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        seasonsAndPointSegment.setTitleTextAttributes(titleTextAttributes, for: .selected)
    } else {
        seasonsAndPointSegment.setTitleTextAttributes(withoutUnderLine, for: .normal)
    }
     if seasonsAndPointSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        seasonsAndPointSegment.setTitleTextAttributes(titleTextAttributes, for: .selected)
    } else {
        seasonsAndPointSegment.setTitleTextAttributes(withoutUnderLine, for: .normal)
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have this as a method inside a class or is it a free function? If the former, what class is it in?

Comment: I'm Using this method in Viewdidload...

Comment: Edit your question to show the exception message?  What is the selector that is unrecognised" what object class is involved?

Comment: Done sir... I have Submitted an Image.

Comment: Usually that error tells you what selector is unrecognized. Is there any more detail on the error itself?

Comment: I remember a similar bug, and I think the solution was to remove the existing underline attribute before doing modifications. Try adding an instruction to remove the underline attribute for "withoutUnderLine" instead of just not setting it.

Comment: Okay... Thanks for reply.